# Meta Tags In Body

Tags: facebook-like, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get my like button on my website www.nacts.com.au to add to the ones on our Facebook page but receive this message:

> You have tags ouside of your . This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.

But it is actually placed like this under PHP

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://developers.facebook.com/schema/" "html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" >
    <head>
    <title>North Australia Career &amp; Training Services</title>
     <meta property="fb:app_id" content="191402794307447" />
     <meta property="og:title" content="North Australia Career & Training Services" />
     <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
     <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nacts.com.au" />
     <meta property="og:image" content="http://nacts.com.au/images/NACTS4.png" />
     <meta property="og:site_name" content="NACTS" />
     <meta property="fb:admins" content="566419298" /> 
     <meta property="og:description" content="North Australia Career & Training Services"> 
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="3123382E32539EBE8C53C2CA69F7510D" />
     <meta name="google-site-verification" content="bExkQFnEooJVIoZIm70CO8H8Yjx_FfyyCC6hNE_SeoA" />
     <meta name="keywords" content=" training rockhampton, training rocky, rockhampton training,training,train,career development,mining,course,Resumes, Resumes Rockhampton, Tenders,Tender Writing, Marketing,business services,Rockhampton Business Services ,Courses,North Rockhampton Training,Industry Courses,Workplace Development,Rockhampton Career Advice,Career Development Rockhampton,RPL,North Australia,career,training Services,funding, Grants" />
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your issue is in the error description.  You have to embed the og: meta tags in the `<head />` section of the HTML code.  Please read more about how open graph tags work here:  http://ogp.me

---

**EDIT**

Based upon the edits to the question, now knowing the URL of www.nacts.com.au, it's much easier to troubleshoot.

I do see one meta tag that is in the BODY section and not in the HEAD. It is `<meta property="fb:page_id" content="148187795268337">`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand?

Comment: 1) Did you read the ogp.me web site?  2) Do you know how edit HTML?

Comment: Thank you for your help I appreciate it immensely. Yes I have read through the site and just confused myself more. I am not a coder however I did build the site so yes I do know how to edit HTML. I'm still missing/not seeing where issue is and it's driving my crazy.

Comment: Did you place the og tags in the head section?  Can you please edit the question add the html code you added for og tags?

Comment: I have placed the updated code. It seems so trivial but just not sure what I’m missing?

Comment: FYI: I edited your question and formatted it so people can see the HTML code you put.

Comment: Please ask as a new question.

Comment: This is such garbage behavior by Facebook. These meta tags add 0 value to the user viewing it. They belong as late in the content delivery as possible, yet Facebook seems to require they come before anything else.